# How to do citing

Tags: citing

Thank you @Johannes_B, @Joseph Wright, @Alexis Pigeon
The problem is solved.

To make my question easier to be understood, I provide steps and files here to reproduce my error.

1. Download template file from http://www.latextemplates.com/templates/theses/1/thesis_1.zip
2. Adding `\cite{Reference1}` in Chapter1.tex on line 12
3. Compile the main.tex file
4. The result is a [?] on page 14 in the output pdf

So my question is how to do citing?

Comment: What if you try `\cite{Reference1}` ?

Comment: it outputs [?] also

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You should also take a look at [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852)

Comment: And you make sure you run latex/bibtex/latex/latex, to set all the cross-references correctly, right? Anyway, you should provide a minimal working example, i.e. in you case your `.tex` and `.bib` files stripped down to the minimum for people here to be able to reproduce your issue. Otherwise, it's just guessing...

Comment: okay, i will try to make it.

Comment: Following the edit: this really does sound like you are missing the 'latex/bibtex/latex/latex' 'recipe' that is needed to get things to work and that has already been linked by @Johannes_B. Unless there is a good reason to think otherwise this looks like a dupe to me.

Comment: Those templates aren't very good to be honest. Be careful, you might run into much more trouble.

Comment: @Johannes_B, then what should I do to fix the citing problem?

Comment: Run the right order of commands, that is `latex`/`bibtex`/`latex`/`latex` on your main file as it is explained in the link i gave you. @AlexisPigeon also told you so and Joseph as well.

Comment: Sorry I missed it and Thank you very much, the problem is solved.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a lack of understanding of the BibTeX workflow.